# How to plot a 2d matrix in python with colorbar? (like imagesc in Matlab)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matlab I can visualize a matrix `data` quite easily with

```
data = rand(10,10); % Createas a 10 x 10 random matrix
imagesc(data);
colorbar;
```

Now I want to do the same thing in python. I already know how to plot a 2d matrix (numpy array):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((10,10))
imshow(np.asarray(img))
```

but I don't know how to add a colorbar to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(np.random.random((50,50)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 20):

Another possibility is to use **[plt.matshow()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html)**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.matshow(np.random.random((50,50)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```